# Is there a better option for including images in my program than "resources" or am I just doing something wrong?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

So I'm a bit of a self-taught programmer.  I learned VB6 in college and used it sporadically for several years.  A few years ago I got back into it and switched over to vb.net.  I'm currently using Visual Studio Community 2019.  I've been learning as I go and have been getting by pretty well.  Lately, though, I'm having an issue that I can't seem to figure out.  Here's the problem:

I have a program I'm writing that is fairly graphic heavy.  It's a game so there are a lot of image assets that I've added to the resources (1752 items currently and most are images).  Everything has been fine, but lately I'm having a lot of issues adding additional images.  I'll get compile failures that won't tell me what the errors are.  I'll get "Out Of Memory" exceptions that say certain images can't be initiated.  I've had to revert to backups several times because I just couldn't undo whatever had gone wrong even if I removed the images I added.

I still have several new images I want to add as part of an update.  I've tried simply dragging and dropping the images to add them and I've tried adding them through the "add resource" button but the results are the same.  I've tried adding the images in smaller batches but I still run into issues.  I tried adding different images to see if the ones I was using were somehow the problem but that didn't help either.

This is one of those things that I accept I may just not know best practices on.  Is there a better way to add images to my program other than putting them into the resources?  Is there something I can do with my resources to prevent these issues?  Any advice would be really appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: I think the main benefit to having dependent files as resources is keeping the entire assembly in a single package.  If that is leading to unacceptable issues with the toolchain, then maybe it would be better to distribute the files separately (either as individual files or in some kind of archive, most likely zip).

Comment: You mention "revert to backups", are you using source control?

Comment: I just saved a copy of the entire directory (one that worked prior to these issues) so that I can go back to it if and when the program gets so broken I can't easily repair it.

Comment: You can build a class Library, used only to store resources. It can be part of the Project, another specific Solution or a shared Project. You then just reference this Library in any Project that needs it. Make the Library export static (`Shared`) methods that allow to retrieve the images by different means (by Index, by Name etc.) -- This Library never changes Version

Comment: I'd suggest that you consider using source control.  git will support a local version history even if you never upload to any kind of central repository.  It makes it easier to manage incremental changes (and rollback if something goes wrong).

Comment: You may consider seeing if there is a difference if you use VS 2022 which is x64. See [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/). Also, you've not stated if you're compiling for x86, x64, or AnyCPU. If "AnyCPU" is "Prefer 32-bit" checked?

Comment: @jimi I'll look at the class library option tomorrow and see how that works.  Thanks.

Comment: @user09938 I may look into VS2022.  I'd been thinking about it anyway.  I'm getting the errors sometimes before I even try to compile, but I'm using x86 as my target CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to Visual Studio 2022 and that helped with the issue to some degree.  One big change was that the compile failures without any reported errors went away.  That was a huge help because it pointed me in the direction of the underlying problem.

I was able to track down a couple of the 1500 new images that were causing the issue.  I'm still not positive what was wrong with them (they appeared to be no different than any of the others) but I rerendered them and now everything is great!  Thanks to everyone for the advice!

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider  accepting this answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)